# Connecting to External Accessory with Wahoo API

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

I am using Wahoo api for an iPhone app which uses Wahoo's external accessory (ANT+ key). I added the framework version 2.3.5 in "Build phases" tab under section "Link Binary With Items". Then, I created a test.h and test.m. I imported the header WFConnector/WFConnector.h and declared a property

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) WFHardwareConnector* hardwareConnector;
```

In test.m, in a method, assume "getHWConnect" I entered the following

```
hardwareConnector = [WFHardwareConnector sharedConnector];    
hardwareConnector.delegate = self;
```

However, when I try to check the status of the ANT+ key using

```
if(hardwareConnector.isCommunicationHWReady)
```

I get the following error

```
"Property 'isCommunicationHWReady' not found on object of type "WFHardwareConnector *"
```

However, the property is there in the header! Check the pictures I've attached below

[image: Error]

[image: Property in Header]

Check this out in [api.wahoofitness.com](http://api.wahoofitness.com/interface_w_f_hardware_connector.html#a8abb006def39ef55ec1e743af0a100d8) as well.

What mistake have I made? Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Did you solve your issue ? Is ANT+ works with latest device like iPhone 6,7,8,10 ?

Comment: sorry buddy, after that project, I haven't done any sort of app development with Wahoo API in the last 5 years..